# Java streams filtering

Tags: java, list, java-8, java-stream

Hello I have a list of dtos which have flag is deleted. I need to filter them and return one.

The logic is that if there is two items in the list and one of them is deleted I fetch non deleted one, but if there is only one item and deleted then I return it.

So basically order is not deleted > deleted > new item.

```
List<Item> existingItems = service.getItems();
existingItems.stream().filter(e -> !e.getIsDeleted()).findAny().orElse(new Item());
```

How can I modify this `Stream` pipeline to implement the required logic?

Comment: So the list has always a maximum size of 2?

Comment: No, it can bet 0 or more

Comment: But a MAXIMUM size of 2? So 0, 1 or 2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve this by sorting on `getIsDeleted`:

```
existingItems.stream()
             .sorted( Comparator.comparing(Item::getIsDeleted ) )
             .findFirst()
             .orElseGet(Item::new);
```

This solution assumes that `existingItems` contains a small number of items.

Comment: Is it possible to pass two conditions for .sorted() for example : Comparator.comparing(Item::getIsDeleted ) and Comparator.comparing(Item::getValidFrom) ?

Comment: Nice answer. One small improvement would be to create the `Item` lazily: `.orElseGet(Item::new)`

Comment: It certainly looks elegant, but it takes `O(nlogn)` time, while a solution without sorting takes linear time at the worst case.

Comment: I've assumed n is small. Otherwise I'd probably push this predicate to the database, or store this list differently

Comment: @DanJo `Comparator.comparing(Item::getIsDeleted).thenComparing(Item::getValidFrom)`

Comment: You can also use `.stream().min(Comparator.comparing(Item::getIsDeleted))`.

Answer (score 7):

You can return the first element of the `List` in `orElse`:

```
existingItems.stream()
             .filter(e -> !e.getIsDeleted())
             .findAny()
             .orElse(existingItems.isEmpty() ? new Item() : existingItems.get(0));
```

Comment: If list will be empty it will not return anything and i need to return new Item() if list is empty

Comment: You should maybe use `existingItems` instead of `list`, just to make it clear.

Answer (score 4):

I joined late. Answer to your comment @Danjo.
using the code from above.

```
existingItems.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(Item::getIsDeleted)
  .thenComparing(Comparator.comparing(Item::getValidFrom)))
             .findFirst()
             .orElse(new Item());
```

Comment: Did you make sure it compiles? Type inference tends to fail across chained comparators.

Comment: No, I didn't get a chance to compile the code. I think it should work as method reference is used. Moreover, the comparator can be explicitly created and added later. Please verify my understanding.

Comment: @shmosel: it will work as long as there is only a single method named `getIsDeleted` in `Item`, so `Item::getIsDeleted` does not need choosing between multiple methods.

Comment: True. I just answered on a comment added by @DanJo. 
Is it possible to pass two conditions for .sorted() for example : Comparator.comparing(Item::getIsDeleted ) and Comparator.comparing(Item::getValidFrom)